# Can't put a window in a style

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, mvvm

I made an mvvm project in WPF.
However, I get an error in my MainWindow.xaml, saying I can't put a window in a style...
This is my MainWindow.xaml:

```
 <Window x:Class="DataValidation.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:BankEn.viewmodel"
        xmlns:v="clr-namespace:BankEn.view"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Window.DataContext>
        <vm:AccountVM/>
    </Window.DataContext>
    <Window.Resources>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type vm:AccountVM}">
            <v:HomePage/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <ContentControl Content="{Binding CurrentPage}"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

the error occurs on `<v: HomePage>`
In my HomePage.xaml I don't use the `<window>` tags ... So I have no idea what the actual problem could be:

```
<UserControl x:Class="BankEn.view.HomePage"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:BankEn.viewmodel"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
        xmlns:cmd="clr-namespace:GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Command;assembly=GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.WPF45"
        xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
        xmlns:rules="clr-namespace:BankEn.Model.rules"
        mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="300" Width="528">

    <UserControl.DataContext>
        <vm:AccountVM/>
    </UserControl.DataContext>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="250"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ListBox Margin="8" ItemsSource="{Binding Accounts}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedAcc}" DisplayMemberPath="AccountHolder"/>
        <StackPanel Margin="8" Grid.Column="1">
            <Label Content="Accountholder:"/>
            <Label FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="10" Height="25px" Content="{Binding SelectedAcc.AccountHolder}"/>
            <Label Content="Accountnumber:"/>
            <Label FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="10" Height="25px" Content="{Binding SelectedAcc.AccountNumber}"/>
            <Label Content="Balance:"/>
            <Label FontWeight="Bold" FontSize="10" Height="25px" Content="{Binding SelectedAcc.Balance}"/>
            <Label Content="Transfer to:"/>
            <ComboBox Name="cboReceiver" SelectedItem="{Binding CboAcc}" ItemsSource="{Binding Path=Accounts}" DisplayMemberPath="AccountHolder" SelectedValuePath="AccountHolder" />
            <Label Content="Amount:"/>
            <TextBox InputScope="Number" Name="Amount"></TextBox>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,16,0,0">
                <Button Content="Transfer money" Command="{Binding UpdateAccount}" CommandParameter="{Binding Text, ElementName=Amount}" Width="250"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: What's the exact error message?

Comment: `Error 1 Can't put a Window in a Style. `

Comment: Is <v:HomePage/> a UserControl ?

Comment: @Maximus yes, second code snippet shows the definition of HomePage, i.e.: UserControl

Comment: UserControl inherits DataContext from Window, both indicate on the same so in this case you can remove it from UserControl, of course it is not the solution for the problem, just notice.

Comment: Your error can not be reproduced using the code you have provided. I copied your code directly into a new project and it loads fine. You'll have to dig around elsewhere in your code to see where you actually have the bad code.